# All divs directly beneath it

Tags: html, css

i would like to ask you what should i do to have divs with products directly beneath.

Live demo: http://lukashamrla.cz/web/index-en.html

I want Gold ring 3 right under Gramophone with no space.

Thanks for any answers.

Comment: jQuery Masonry is the best option here.

Comment: i'll have a look at it, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Jquery Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/) will organize your items to have a **Pintrest** like effect which will put your *Gold Ring 3* in the correct spot.

It is not a trivial problem, unfortunately.

If you don't want to do that, you can create two columns with fixed widths and split each of your items between the two.